# Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - env -u GIT_CONFIG git -C "[...]/.cocoapods/repos/master" config --get remote.origin.url (Windows 10)

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm trying to do a 'pod install' in a ReactNative plugin folder but am getting the error seen in the title. I am running this on Windows 10. Error template below:

#### Command

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.5.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
    RubyGems : 3.0.2
        Host : Unable to find an executable (No such file or directory - sw_vers)  ()
       Xcode : -version) ()
         Git : git version 2.15.0.windows.1
Ruby lib dir : C:/Ruby25-x64/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ f403c4e44587a5045a9ed48ddca2ea6fc108b66b
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'RNPhotoEditor' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RNPhotoEditor
  pod 'iOSPhotoEditor', :git => 'https://github.com/prscX/photo-editor'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name.include?('iOSPhotoEditor')
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

#### Error

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - env -u GIT_CONFIG git -C "C:/Users/Owner/.cocoapods/repos/master" config --get remote.origin.url
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:448:in ``'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:448:in `repo_git'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:46:in `url'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:347:in `block in source_with_url'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:346:in `each'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:346:in `find'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:346:in `source_with_url'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:18:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:873:in `block in sources'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:872:in `map'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:872:in `sources'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:780:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:779:in `resolve_dependencies'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:88:in `analyze'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/pod:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

If I go to that line I find the following:

```
def repo_git(args, include_error: false)
  command = "env -u GIT_CONFIG git -C \"#{repo}\" " << args.join(' ')
  command << ' 2>&1' if include_error
  (`#{command}` || '').strip #<--this line here
end
```

If I just run 'ruby env' I get the following back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby: No such file or directory -- env (LoadError)
```

Plus if I run just 'env' I get expected not found error message: ''env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'. So I think this means that the system doesn't recognize the env command, however it seems to be necessary to run 'pod install'.

I've done some googling on getting env to work on windows but am pretty sure I'm not googling my problem correctly as I am finding no results. I think so far I have installed ruby, ruby gems, and cocoapods trying to get some RN plugin working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that Cocoapods actually supports running on Windows? It appears that they only support macOS right now.

Comment: @HolgerJust No, I'm not sure of that. I was following the install instructions for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-photo-editor. I thought I could develop RN apps on windows, even though I had to build on mac for the final iOS push?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late, but just in case, I hit the same error running the same command on linux, with cocoapods versions `1.5.3` and `1.7.2`.

The only solution I found was to run it on mac. The missing file `sw_vers` seems to be an apple specific utility that [returns the version of the OS](https://ss64.com/osx/sw_vers.html).

Cocoapods [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started) also mention:

> CocoaPods manages library dependencies for your Xcode projects.

and although there is no clear mention of it anywhere on the site, it doesn't seem to run properly outside of macOS.